# .htaccess is not rewriting my url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i'm quite new to .htaccess file and I nees a bit of help..

I have a Greek site and I want to have urls like επικοινωνία.html. However, I haven't managed to translate successfully using htaccess file.

My code, for example, is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule επικοινωνία.html contact.html
```

However, the url showing in the browser is not changing at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: This may be a file encoding issue, can you try a test to redirect something like `foo` to `επικοινωνία.html` to see what URL you end up with in the browser's location bar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^επικοινωνία\.html$ /contact.html [L,B,R]
```